# How to sortrows in VBA, instead of Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vba, sorting, excel

I have a question about sorting an array in VBA. Previously I programmed in Matlab and I would like to do something like: P = sortrows(P,3), but using VBA. That organizes a matrix by the 3 column.

Is it possible to do something similar in VBA?

Does anyone can help me ?

Thank u!

Augusto Mello

Comment: Try adapting Crocus Crow's answer here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?41938-Solved-sort-multi-dimensional-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Range.sort

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
Range("C" & lastrow).Sort
```

Comment: Thank u for the quick reply!

Comment: I have the array (1,2,3) and I would like to do a circular shift in order to obtain for example (3,1,2) or (2,3,1).

In Matlab I know how to do that using the following code:

    Y = circshift(A,K)
Can u please help me with this task?

I'd appreciate any sample codes...

Comment: I do not know why I can not ask. Can u help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075742/how-to-shift-an-array-circularly-on-vba

Comment: how can I get rid of them?

Comment: if the qns is not answered yet, just delete the qn away.. btw i answered the qn..